# why does VBA exit my for loop early and why aren't cell values being stored in my array properly?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I wrote this macro to pull data from a separate workbook to do some string manipulation. (Not shown) Eventually the code uses the data stored in the arrays created to create work instructions. Code shown below with one section working as intended (bend array creation), the second section will not (csk array creation). When I step through the code it will not go to the 'next i' and exits the if statement entirely on the first iteration.

```
nbends = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("M6:M" & lastrow), "BEND RADIUS")
ncsksf = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("M6:M" & lastrow), "CSK FARSIDE")
ncsksn = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("M6:M" & lastrow), "CSK NEARSIDE")

ReDim Bends(1 To nbends, 1 To 5)
ReDim Csksn(1 To nscksn, 1 To 3)

'' Bend array creation
On Error Resume Next
Set r = Range("M6:M" & lastrow).Find(what:="BEND RADIUS", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    firstaddress = r.Address
    addressrow = Right(firstaddress, 2)
    Bends(1, 1) = Range("A" & addressrow)
    Bends(1, 2) = Range("C" & addressrow)
    Bends(1, 3) = Range("A" & addressrow + 1)
    Bends(1, 4) = Range("M" & addressrow + 1)
    Bends(1, 5) = Range("B" & addressrow + 1)
    Do
        For i = LBound(Bends) + 1 To UBound(Bends)
            Set r = Range("M" & addressrow & ":M" & lastrow).Find(what:="BEND RADIUS", LookIn:=xlValues)
            firstaddress = r.Address
            addressrow = Right(firstaddress, 2)
            Bends(i, 1) = Range("A" & addressrow)
            Bends(i, 2) = Range("C" & addressrow)
            Bends(i, 3) = Range("A" & addressrow + 1)
            Bends(i, 4) = Range("M" & addressrow + 1)
            Bends(i, 5) = Range("B" & addressrow + 1)
        Next i
    Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstaddress
End If

'' Csks array creation
On Error Resume Next
Set r = Range("M6:M" & lastrow).Find(what:="CSK NEARSIDE", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    firstaddress = r.Address
    addressrow = Right(firstaddress, 2)
    Csksn(1, 1) = Range("A" & addressrow)
    Csksn(1, 2) = Range("B" & addressrow)
    Csksn(1, 3) = Range("M" & addressrow)
    Debug.Print addressrow
    Do
        For i = LBound(Csksn) + 1 To UBound(Csksn)
            Set r = Range("M" & addressrow & ":M" & lastrow).Find(what:="CSK NEARSIDE", LookIn:=xlValues)
            firstaddress = r.Address
            addressrow = Right(firstaddress, 2)
            Csksn(i, 1) = Range("A" & addressrow)
            Csksn(i, 2) = Range("B" & addressrow)
            Csksn(i, 3) = Range("M" & addressrow)
            Debug.Print r
            Debug.Print firstaddress
            Debug.Print addressrow
        Next i
    Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstaddress
End If
```

I fixed this by changing the for loop parameters to

```
For i = 2 To ncsksn
            Set r = Range("M" & addressrow & ":M" & lastrow).Find(what:="CSK NEARSIDE", LookIn:=xlValues)
            firstaddress = r.Address
            addressrow = Right(firstaddress, 2)
            Csksn(i, 1) = Range("A" & addressrow)
            Csksn(i, 2) = Range("B" & addressrow)
            Csksn(i, 3) = Range("M" & addressrow)
            Debug.Print r
            Debug.Print firstaddress
            Debug.Print addressrow
        Next i
    Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstaddress
End If
```

and it will print the values for each variable (r, firstaddress, addressrow) at each iteration of the for loop; but when i go to print the array using this loop nothing appears.

```
For i = LBound(Csksn) To UBound(Csksn)
    For j = LBound(Csksn) To UBound(Csksn)
        Debug.Print i, j, Csksn(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
```

What am I missing here?
Thank you all for your knowledge

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` hides errors. Comment it out and re-run - do you get an error?

Comment: `For i = LBound(Csksn, 1) to UBound(Csksn, 1)`; `For j = LBound(Csksn, 2) to UBound(Csksn, 2)`.

Comment: `addressrow = Right(firstaddress, 2)` - no, use `r.Row` to get the row number. There's no need to parse the row from a range address.

Comment: Well i can't nest 'j' into 'i' because i want specific data in each column.. i have done the other 2 and still have the same issue.. leaving the for loop after 1 iteration and not saving the data to the array. Based on my data set i should have 4 rows of data.

Comment: Also i am getting no errors in either loop when i comment that line out